# Camel exchange inout is not maintaining the exception in exchange

Tags: apache-camel, esb, eip

I created a camel route without INOUT exchange pattern and the route looks like

```
direct:start > bean:myBean?method=handle
```

I'm sending payload using ProducerTemplate's send method

```
Exchange response = producerTemplate.send(endpointUri, exchange);
```

I set the exception on exchange in the bean's handle method, but its not retained in the response.

Is there something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where camel's hiding the exception. Since I marked the exchange as handled and marked for rollback, camel is setting the exception to null and moved it to properties.

I was able to retrieve it using

```
result.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should throw an exception from the bean if you want to signal an exception.

Comment: I did, but traced camel internal processing and found that RedeliveryErrorHandler is setting it to null.